# MapBox iOS SDK framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to implement MapBox SDK, but i have issue:

[image]

I followed all these steps:

1. Obtain the map ID for your hosted map by clicking Publish and copying the Map ID;
2. Download the latest SDK binary release from the downloads and drag MapBox.framework into your project’s Frameworks section, making sure to link it in your target;
3. Add -ObjC to your app target’s Other Linker Flags build setting in order to ensure that the SDK’s static library has all symbols loaded, even for categories;

   [image]
4. Add the following libraries to your app target’s Link Binary With Libraries build phase:

   - CoreLocation.framework (required for location services);
   - QuartzCore.framework (required because of advanced layer manipulation);
   - libsqlite3.dylib (required for MBTiles and caching support);
   - libz.dylib (required for UTFGrid interactivity).

[image]

And i'm trying to test it with following code:

```
#import <MapBox/MapBox.h>

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RMMapBoxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"examples.map-z2effxa8"];

    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

I'm doing same steps over and over, but same errors showing up. I think that i'm missing something. Can some one tell me what i'm missing?

**EDIT: everything works on simulator, but on device i'm getting errors.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io2Df.png) . It might help.

See image below if link doesn't work

[image]

Cheers.